# PHP constructor invocation syntax

Tags: php, syntax

Usually I create a new object invocating his constructor the usual way:

```
$instance= new Class();
```

Lately, I'm reading a lot of code with an alternative syntax (without the parentesys):

```
$instance= new Class;
```

There are substantial differences between the two methods or are they equivalent?

I haven't found references on this topic 'till now.

Comment: As far as I know, unless you need to pass parameters to your constructor, both expressions are identical. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: As far I know, I agree with you. I would like to be sure this is an intended feature, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference.

You're right about this being hard to prove. [The Basics](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) introduces the `new` keyword but all examples have parentheses and no mention is made of their optionality.

**Edit:** best I can find are examples from the [official documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/oop4.constructor.php) such as:

> ```
> // This will call B() as a constructor
> $b = new B;
> ```

Comment: Just what I was searching. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with PHP, but the latter probably invokes the default constructor, while the former invokes the constructor with no parameters.

Comment: Unfortunately, PHP doesn't support multiple constructors. Nice try though. :)

Comment: Re: No multiple constructors.  True, however you can omit them and if default values are provided in the signature they will be substituted in when the call is made.